# How to pass the target function of std::thread constructor as an argument

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I can do this to start my thread:

```
int main_test() {
  // do something...
  return 0;
}

std::thread* myThread;

void myFunction() {
  myThread = new std::thread(main_test);
}
```

How do I pass `main_test` as an argument to `myFunction`, so the same function can be used to start the thread using different target functions? What would the signature of `myFunction` be then?

I guess what I don't understand is how the templated version of the `std::thread` constructor is invoked with a specified type.

Comment: You can use the same code as `std::thread` uses to accept arguments in the constructor. I don't understand your question about the identity, do you mean the type?

Comment: On a side note, a dynamic allocation with the new operator is not necessary in your case. Create it on the stack like `myThread = std::thread(main_test);`.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I think by identity he means the signature of the function.

Comment: Yes signature, thanks. Fixed now

Comment: Still, you basically can copy the code from `std::thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass main_test as an argument to myFunction, so the same function can be used to start the thread using different target functions?

You can pass the poiter to your function as an argument

```
void myFunction(int (*func)()) {
myThread = new std::thread(func);
}

int callSelector(int someCriteria)
{
    if (someCriteria == 0) {
        myFunction(main_test1);
    }
    else {
        myFunction(main_test2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> std::thread myThread;
> ```

The type of `myThread` is `std::thread`.

> ```
> myThread = new std::thread(main_test);
> ```

`new std::thread(main_test)` returns `std::thread*`. You cannot assign `std::thread*` into a `std::thread`. The program is ill-formed.

Solution: There appears to be no reason to use dynamic allocation. Simply assign a temporary object like this:

```
myThread = std::thread(main_test);
```

> How do I pass main_test as an argument to myFunction, so the same function can be used to start the thread using different target functions? What would the identity of myFunction be then?

You can make your `myFunction` a template with exactly the same arguments as `std::thread` has, and forward everything. Or, if you want to keep it simple, you can use a function pointer.